# Qt Mac binary installs won't run on PowerPC/G5

Tags: qt, macos, powerpc

I installed the 32 bit Cocoa binary for mac on a G5, none of the Qt apps would run, so I uninstalled it, installed the Carbon binary, & none of those apps would run. What am I doing wrong?  I get error messages saying the "application is not supported on this platform".

- Mac 10.5.8
- Xcode 3.1.2
- Qt 4.7.3

1.8 GHz G5 with 2.5 GB RAM.

Comment: I am sorry, but I really don't understand the question at all. What binary are you talking about? Is it a program you downloaded? Is it a program that you are writing? Please give us more details that are relevant to the question you are asking.

Comment: @sosborn I understand those as the binary Qt frameworks: there’s one for Cocoa, another one for Carbon. See [this page](http://qt.nokia.com/downloads/qt-for-open-source-cpp-development-on-mac-os-x/).

Comment: By the way, the page I’ve linked above states that the Cocoa binary package is for Intel only.

Comment: Ok, so you are having a problem when you install the binaries? Or are you having a problem when you try to compile your code?

Comment: A likely reason is that your programs haven’t been built for the `ppc` architecture. Run `lipo -info` on your binaries to check that. If you want to build universal binaries, you need to use `-arch i386 -arch x86_64 -arch ppc` (or some variant of that) when building your programs. Not sure how this works with Qt, though.

Comment: Qt can be built for ppc, I don't know if the current version can or can not. Try building the dynamic library from source on the ppc.

Comment: You want `qt-mac-opensource-X.Y.Z.dmg` (where X.Y.Z <= 4.6.4, as I understand it; newer versions can be built from source), not `qt-mac-cocoa-opensource-X.Y.Z.dmg` or `qt-mac-cocoa-carbon-X.Y.Z.dmg`.  (I believe 4.7 changed the default from carbon to cocoa, and that this is also when Trolltech/Nokia stopped building ppc/i386 universal – I have no clue why, and they don't seem to have made any official announcement of this.)  Anyway, you can grab it at ftp://ftp.qt.nokia.com/qt/source/qt-mac-opensource-4.6.4.dmg

Answer (score 1):

You want `qt-mac-opensource-X.Y.Z.dmg` (where X.Y.Z <= 4.6.4, as I understand it; newer versions can be built from source), not `qt-mac-cocoa-opensource-X.Y.Z.dmg` or `qt-mac-cocoa-carbon-X.Y.Z.dmg`.

(I believe 4.7 changed the default from carbon to cocoa, and that this is also when Trolltech/Nokia stopped building ppc/i386 universal – I have no clue why, and they don't seem to have made any official announcement of this.)

Anyway, you can grab it at ftp://ftp.qt.nokia.com/qt/source/qt-mac-opensource-4.6.4.dmg.